# How to change dimentions of placeholder box in css?

Tags: css, placeholder

I want to make placeholder box big [like comment box on the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwTti.png), however I'm facing difficulties to do it. I would appreciate help

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<textarea>` tag

or a division with `contenteditable='true'` which is NOT a common way to do this

Here is an example of `textarea`

`<textarea name="comment" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>`

I suggest you to use `cols` and `rows` instead of `width` and `height` because they respect words and line sizes